# How do I add items to a List when in a callback method? (Microsoft graph api)

Tags: java, android, list, rest, microsoft-graph-api

Have been having some serious trouble with this one. I am trying to add some items to a list in the callback method called success. When I am doing this it will only work while debugging the method. But when I try to run the code normally it won't add anything to the list. It just returns an empty list.

```
class GraphServiceController {
    private final IGraphServiceClient mGraphServiceClient;
    private ArrayList<User> users;    

    public enum StorageState {
        NOT_AVAILABLE, WRITEABLE, READ_ONLY
    }

    public GraphServiceController() {
        mGraphServiceClient = GraphServiceClientManager.getInstance().getGraphServiceClient();
        users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void apiUsers(){

        final IUserCollectionRequest userRequest = mGraphServiceClient.getUsers().buildRequest();
        userRequest.get(new ICallback<IUserCollectionPage>() {
            @Override
            public void success(IUserCollectionPage iUserCollectionPage) {
                addUsers(iUserCollectionPage);                
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(ClientException ex) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void addUsers(IUserCollectionPage input){
        for(User user : input.getCurrentPage()) {
            users.add(user);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can post a full example someone can try to help you. If it works when debugging it could well be a race condition i.e. stopping the program in the debugger allows other threads to run first, so when you step through from your breakpoint the other threads have completed setup / init of dependent required data etc.

Comment: input.getCurrentPage() this is the single user data? because ur arraylist object is User

Comment: @davidfrancis how would i go with posting a full example? U guys want a github link or do u want me to copy all the classes in a text? Sorry, not that experience with stackoverflow yet

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran this returns a list with user objects

Comment: @J.Verlaek Please post the smallest amount of working runnable code that demos the issue, just put it in the question